# I need to use MS OAuth2 code from Azure login using react-native-azure-auth. Only accessToken and rawIdToken are accessible. Solutions to get "code"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, azure-authentication

```
async authorize(options = {}) {
        const scope = new Scope(options.scope)

        const { clientId, client, agent } = this
        const {nonce, state, verifier} = await agent.generateRequestParams()

        let requestParams = {
            ...options,
            clientId,
            scope: scope.toString(),
            responseType: 'code' + (scope.toString().includes('openid') ? ' id_token': ''),
            response_mode: 'fragment', // 'query' is unsafe and not supported, the hash fragment is also default
            state: state,
            nonce: nonce,
            code_challenge_method: 'plain',
            code_challenge: verifier
        }
        const loginUrl = this.client.loginUrl(requestParams)

        let redirectUrl = await agent.openWeb(loginUrl, options.ephemeralSession)

        if (!redirectUrl || !redirectUrl.startsWith(client.redirectUri)) {
            throw new AuthError({
                json: {
                    error: 'aa.redirect_uri.not_expected',
                    error_description: `Expected ${client.redirectUri} but got ${redirectUrl}`
                },
                status: 0
            })
        }

        // Response is returned in hash, but we want to get parsed object
        // Query can be parsed, therefore lets replace hash sign with '?' mark
        redirectUrl = redirectUrl.replace('#','?') // replace only first one
        const urlHashParsed = url.parse(redirectUrl, true).query
        const {
            code,
            state: resultState,
            error
        } = urlHashParsed

        if (error) {
            throw new AuthError({json: urlHashParsed, status: 0})
        }

        if (resultState !== state) {
            throw new AuthError({
                json: {
                    error: 'aa.state.invalid',
                    error_description: 'Invalid state received in redirect url'
                },
                status: 0
            })
        }
        
        const tokenResponse = await client.exchange({
            code,
            scope: scope.toString(),
            code_verifier: verifier
        })

        if (tokenResponse.refreshToken) {
            this.client.cache.saveRefreshToken(tokenResponse)
        }
        if (tokenResponse.accessToken) {
            let accessToken = await this.client.cache.saveAccessToken(tokenResponse)
            return accessToken
        } else {
            // we have to have at least id_token in respose
            return new BaseTokenItem(tokenResponse, this.clientId)
        }
    }
```

This is the code from src/webauth/index.js from react-native-azure-auth.

I need to access the value of `code` which is destructured from `urlHashParsed`.

Please help, thanks in advance.

I tried to get the value using imports. But `code` is not exposed by default.

This is highly unlikely scenario of usage, but my API requires the OAuth2 token to work rather than the `accessToken` or the `rawIdToken`.